# How to get the option value on change by clicking on the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is the code example, I need to get the option value on change by clicking on the button?
I am showing a form on popup window, in that form we have a
drop down item.

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{media url='wysiwyg/123.png'}}" alt="">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3 class="display-5">product heading1</h3>
      <hr>
      <p>product content goes here...!</p>
      <p><a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-default" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Request For Your product</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<select style='width:100%;box-sizing:border-box; font-size: 14px;font-weight: lighter;' name='LEADCF46'>
  <option value='-None-'>-None-</option>
  <option value='11 name'>11 product name</option>
  <option value='12 name'>12 product name</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You may be new to javascript.any way please search before post it.please refer this link it may help you.https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: @Kumaran, I have already seen that w3schools but, what my requirement as follows: step #1 On page I have two buttons<button type="button">btn1</button><button type="button">btn2</button> Step #2 by clicking on btn1, showing a form inside the model window Step #3 By clicking on btn1 I may get drop down value="11" and by clicking on btn2, I may get drop down value="2". I'm not going to write any logics. Any help please

Comment: what javascript have you tried to make this possible?  Your post has a javascript tag.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
 var product = document.getElementById("11"); 
 var product = document.getElementById("12"); 
</script>

Comment: So total there are two button with two modals and you want to show "11 name" value by clicking on button1 and "12 name" value by clicking on button2.is that what you want ?

Comment: @Krishna Savani, Yes that is true

Comment: Do you only need to retrieve the value of the select when clicking the button? Because your question says "on change", which makes it a bit confusing. Anyway, te be able to use `getElementById`, the element should have an `id`. Start from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have work on your requirement please check below code and run as i have took two buttons and get selected value:

```
    <div class="container">
    <button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form" value="11 name" onclick="myFunction('11 name')">
    See Modal with Form
    </button>  
    <button type="button"  id="btn2" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form" value="12 name" onclick="myFunction('12 name')">
    See Modal with Form
    </button> 
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header border-bottom-0">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Create Account</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="hidden" id="btnmodal1">
                      <input type="hidden" id="btnmodal2">
                        <label for="email1">Email address</label>
                        <input  class="form-control" id="email1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Your information is safe with us.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password1">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <select id="selectBox1" style='width:100%;box-sizing:border-box; font-size: 14px;font-weight: lighter;' name='LEADCF46'>
                    <option value='none'>none</option>
                        <option value='11 name'>11 product name</option>
                        <option value='12 name'>12 product name</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer border-top-0 d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success submirrt" onclick="myFunction1()">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="valueeee1"></div>
<div class="valueeee2"></div>

<script>

function myFunction1() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox1");
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    $(".valueeee2").html(" <b>"+selectedValue+"</b>.");

    $("#form .close").click();
    $("#selectBox1 option[value='"+selectedValue+"']").attr("selected", false);
}


function myFunction(btnvalues) {
   $("#selectBox1 option[value='"+btnvalues+"']").attr("selected", true)


}

  </script>
```

Comment: The moment I clicked on the "btn1" by default value should select "11 name" by clicking on "btn2" by default value should be select "12 name"

Comment: You can give selected attribute if you want to take value as default value (edited my code) or let me know where I misunderstand your question

Comment: I don't want to show two different model window's just because of code will become duplicate and lengthy, so what I want is I can handle the selected value with in single model window for both the buttons.

Comment: okay, I understood. I have edited my code again and managed with only one model.please check

Comment: <script>
function myFunction(btnvalues) {
   $("#selectBox1 option[value='"+btnvalues+"']").attr("selected", true)
}
  </script>

Comment: I have modified according to my requirement and working fine.... Thank you @Krishna Savani.